# What is the objective of an ObjectMapper?

Tags: c#, architecture, object-object-mapping

I don't understand why in Object Oriented development people are using some ObjectMapper class. Could you explain me what is the purpose of this kind of class? I'm also looking for documentation about it. I found a lot of information explaining how to create it but nothing about how and why to use it. Do you know where I can find a good article, blog on this (in C# if possible).

A sub-question to be sure to understand. Are ObjectMapper something used in C++?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `ObjectMapper` a c# class?  Which assembly do you see it in?  Is your question about `AutoMapper`?

Comment: custom ObjetcMapper are used in several project but is not a .NET class. You can find many ObjectMapper code on GitHub, CodePlex or here.

Comment: Are you asking whether `ObjectMapper` is available in C#?  Or is the question where mapper objects are useful in general?

Comment: where mapper objects are useful in general... if they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object to Object mapping is not a programming language related question.

There are plenty of useful scenarios when Object to Object mapping comes in handy.

One common scenario is when you have designed your business object model and developed your business services that deal with those objects, within your domain application layer. Now, what if you want to expose your data to any UI and/or clients? You obviously do not want to expose business objects. Here comes the mapping! You might transform your business objects to DTO’s if you’re dealing with web services. You might transform them to ViewModels if the consuming UI is an MVC application…

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

ObjectMapper

This mapper (or, data binder, or codec) provides functionality for converting between Java objects (instances of JDK provided core classes, beans), and matching JSON constructs. It will use instances of [JsonParser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.html) and [JsonGenerator](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator.html) for implementing actual reading/writing of JSON.

As far as I know, the ObjectMapper class is not related to C++. Indeed, it is something related to Java. Hope it helps. In either case, you can refer to below link for your knowledge,

http://www.massapi.com/class/ob/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: Java object?  I think the OP was in the context of c#, no?

Comment: Yes, but what I found was related to JSON and JAVA only, let me know if you find something other than mentioned language..

Comment: No, I think your answer is correct.  I'm wondering what this has to do with C# at the moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Hiren Pandya points out, `ObjectMapper` is a java class that helps in the serialization and deserialization of java objects to and from json.

In general, this is helpful when you have matching json properties (and structure) and you don't want to write all of that mapping code yourself.

Object mappers as a pattern (even more general) can be useful in many scenarios.  Anytime you have two representations (classes) that are logically part of the same concept, you may want to copy data from one to the other.

I hope this helps, however, as I write it sounds pretty general.  Maybe if you give a specific case where you feel it might be needed it would be easier to address.